# dynamic array key additions

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, key-value

Here is my precode...

```
$keys = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
$number = 10;
```

And here is my code...

```
eval('$array[\''.implode('\'][\'',$keys).'\'] = $number;');
```

Using this, I get the following result...

```
Array (
    [a] => Array
        (
            [b] => Array
                (
                    [c] => Array
                        (
                            [d] => 10
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Now, the problem is that this is the exact result I want, but I don't want to use `eval()`.

As input to my code, I have a list of `keys` and a `number`. The `number` should be set to the value of the `keys` array being used to generate child-based `keys` for a certain array `$array`.

Is there a different way that I can achieve this? I don't want to overwrite the keys/numbers with new values as the code works - `eval()` preserves this already, so my new code should do the same.

Comment: There is a point where I have to ask why in the world you're doing this before I'll answer the question. Why would you want this structure? And is having such a rigid structure actually damaging your project? Surely there must be better storage methods in existence?

Comment: i'd have to spend about an hour writing up the full explanation of what unique situation has arisen for this requirement. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full code example showing how it would work. Whats important is that you use a reference to the array so you can modify it:

```
<?php
    $keys = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'); 
    $number = 10;

    $org_array = array(
        "a" => "string",
        "z" => array( "k" => false)
      );

    function write_to_array(&$array, $keys, $number){
      $key = array_shift($keys);
      if(!is_array($array[$key])) $array[$key] = array();
      if(!empty($keys)){
        write_to_array($array[$key], $keys, $number);
      } else {
        $array[$key] = $number;
      }
    }

    write_to_array($org_array, $keys, $number);

    print_r($org_array);
?>
```

Comment: this ones the closest, but again, doesn't work for the case where the array is: array('a' => 'meow') and the keys array is: array('a', 'b', 'c').

I get a Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference...

Comment: @onassar  I misunderstood what you meant by previous values. I updated two parts in the code, the `$org_array['a']` is now set to a string to test, and I changed the `isset` test to an `is_array` test. Now if the key exists as something other than an array is is overwritten vs. extended.

Comment: follow up: what about this case for deletion:
eval('unset($array[\''.implode('\'][\'',$keys).'\']);');

?

Answer (score 3):

Please note that the code below (which you evaluate) will generate a warning, and will therefore not work on projects with error reporting up to the max:

```
$array = array();
$array['a']['b'] = 42; // $array['a'] is not an array... yet
```

Since you're using PHP 5, you can work with references to manipulate your array while traversing the branch of your tree that you wish to modify.

```
$current = & $array;

foreach ($keys as $key):

  if (!isset($current[$key]) || !is_array($current[$key]))
    $current[$key] = array();

  $current = & $current[$key];

endforeach;

$current = $value;
```

Edit: corrected for avoiding warnings and conflicts.

Comment: So why doesn't it throw an error on the second round where you effectively set `$array['a'] = $array['b']` since `a` is not an array yet either. Anyway, +1 since this works great and is way shorter than my answer.

Comment: firstly, what error does it generate? i have my reporting up the max, including deprecation warnings, and i dont see anything.

your code works for cases where array is empty or with keys that aren't a potential conflict. but if the array looks like this: array('a' => 'b') and the keys looks like this array('a', 'orange') I get: 
Fatal error: Cannot create references to/from string offsets nor overloaded objects in ...

Answer (score 1):

```
function deepmagic($levels, $value)
{
    if(count($levels) > 0)
    {
        return array($levels[0] => deepmagic(array_slice($levels, 1),
            $value));
    }
    else
    {
        return $value;
    }
}

$a = deepmagic(Array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), 10);

var_dump($a);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  ["a"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["b"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["c"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["d"]=>
        int(10)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That one doesn't work for array's with existing keys/values either. Hmmm.

Comment: So then use array_keys() or array_values() as desired before passing the array.