# Multidimensional array from string

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have this string which I want to put in a multidimensional array.

Edit : The number of subfolders in the string are dynamic .. from zero sub folders to 10

```
<?php
       $string ="Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/filename1\n";
       $string .=" Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/filename2\n";
       $string .=" Folder4/Folder2/Folder3/filename3\n";
?>
```

I want the following array returned

```
<?php
 Array
(
    [Folder1] => Array
        (
            [Folder2] => Array
                (
                    [Folder3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => filename1
                            [1] => filename2
                        )

                )

        )

    [Folder4] => Array
        (
            [Folder2] => Array
                (
                    [Folder3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => filename3
                        )

                )

        )

)
?>
```

What would be the most efficient way to accomplish this ?

And for the fun of it let's say this array will be send to the other side of the world and it wants to return to a string. How would we do that ?

Comment: Well, if you have a string, and you ultimately want a string, why would you want an array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [String with array structure to Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537148/string-with-array-structure-to-array)

Comment: Because some would like to output it as array , and some would like to save it as a string in DB.  Sending both would be an option, but is not very efficient.

Comment: @Paolo_Mulder Please post your desired output when you have a pathless filename in your input string.  This is an interesting question, but I think you need to have an all-encompassing parent array to hold pathless filenames.  Here is what I am kicking around: https://3v4l.org/UGK0l

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could borrow pieces of code from <del>this class (link no longer available)</del>, specifically the `_processContentEntry` method.

Here's a modified version of the method that does the job:

```php
function stringToArray($path)
{
    $separator = '/';
    $pos = strpos($path, $separator);

    if ($pos === false) {
        return array($path);
    }

    $key = substr($path, 0, $pos);
    $path = substr($path, $pos + 1);

    $result = array(
        $key => stringToArray($path),
    );

    return $result;
}
```

The output of

```php
var_dump(stringToArray('a/b/c/d'));
```

Will be

```php
array(1) {
  ["a"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["b"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["c"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(1) "d"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I suppose that's what you need :)

---

**UPDATE**

As per your comment, here's how you can process a string separated by new line characters:

```php
$string = "Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/filename1\n";
$string .= " Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/filename2\n";
$string .= " Folder4/Folder2/Folder3/filename3\n";

// split string into lines
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $string);

// trim all entries
$lines = array_map('trim', $lines);

// remove all empty entries
$lines = array_filter($lines);

$output = array();

// process each path
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    // split each line by /
    $struct = stringToArray($line);

    // merge new path into the output array
    $output = array_merge_recursive($output, $struct);
}

print_r($output);
```

P.S.
To convert this array to a string, just call [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), however I see no reason to convert it to an array and then back to what it was.

Comment: This will return a different array. My example do not contain 3 strings but 1 string composed of 3 lines. Try it yourself. But thanks for pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Added code to process your multi-line strings. Now it outputs the exact same array as you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think this what you want,

```
$string ="Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/filename1\n";
$string .="Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/filename2\n";
$string .="Folder4/Folder2/Folder3/filename3\n";


$string_array_1 = explode("\n", $string);

$array_need = array();

foreach($string_array_1 as $array_values)
{
        if($array_values)
        {
            $folders =  explode("/", $array_values);
            $array_need[$folders[0]][$folders[1]][$folders[2]][] = $folders[3];
        }
    }

print_r($array_need);
```

Comment: It is great, but not dynamic. What if the number of subfolders change  Folder5/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/filename4

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved recursively in another way by taking the items from the beginning of the array and when the last item is reached just return it.

```
function make_tree( $arr ){
   if( count($arr) === 1){
      return array_pop( $arr );
   }else{
      $result[ array_shift( $arr )] = make_tree( $arr ) ; 
   }
   return $result;
}

$string  = "Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/filename1\n";
$string .= "Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/filename2\n";
$string .= "Folder4/Folder2/Folder3/filename3\n";

$string = trim( $string );

$files_paths = explode( PHP_EOL, $string);

$result = [];

foreach ($files_paths as $key => $value) {
   $parted = explode( '/', $value );
   $tree = make_tree( $parted );
   $result = array_merge_recursive( $result, $tree );
   
}
var_dump( $result );
```