# I do not understand what this code is doing in PHP

Tags: php

I have this code,

```
// TEMP VAR
$temp = &$files;
// BUILD ARRAY STRUCTURE
while(count($file['path'])) {
    // GET DIRECTORY
    $directory = array_shift($file['path']);
    // DIRECTORY NOT SET
    if(!isset($temp[$directory])) {
        // SET DIRECTORY
        $temp[$directory] = array();
    }
    // GO INTO ARRAYS NEXT DIRECTORY
    $temp = &$temp[$directory];
}
```

I got it from the answer to this question,

[String with array structure to Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537148/string-with-array-structure-to-array)

I know what it does, but not how it does it, could anyone please explain to me line by line what is happening?

Thank you all.

Comment: Which line, specifically, don't you understand?  You have a descriptive comment on every single line...

Comment: -1 http://www.emilvikstrom.se/whyidownvote.html (What have you read? Are you new to the language? What is your goal?)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I do not understand what the `&` is doing on both occasions, I know it something to do with `reference` but I looked at the docs and still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

An ampersand in this use is a reference. See [this article](http://www.webmaster-source.com/2010/02/25/why-do-some-php-variables-have-an-ampersand-before-them/)

```
$variable = 'Lorem ipsum';
$new = &$variable;
$variable = 'Some new data';
echo $new; //Prints "Some new data"
```