# Recursive array structured

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String with array structure to Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537148/string-with-array-structure-to-array)

I have an array as such

```
$foo = array();
$foo['/'] = 'value';
$foo['/foo'] = 'value';
$foo['/foo/bar'] = 'value';
$foo['/test'] = 'value';
$foo['/test/tester'] = 'value';
$foo['/hello'] = 'value';
$foo['/hello/world'] = 'value';
$foo['/hello/world/blah'] = 'value';
```

What I need to do is store these sub-pages in a tree-like structure, so instead it needs to be automatically converted to:

```
   $foo = array(
    '/' => array(
        'value' => 'value',
        'children' => array(
            '/foo' => array(
                'value' => 'value',
                'children' => array(
                    '/foo/bar' => array(
                        'value' => 'value',
                        'children' => array()
    );
```

What I figured I would be doing, is something like:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach( $foo as $key => $val )
{
    $bits = explode('/', $key);

    foreach( $bits as $bit )
    {
        $newArray[$bit] = array('val' => $val);
    }
}

print_r($newArray);
```

Except I somehow need to go into the newArray, and keep track of how deep I am into the array.  Does anyone have an example script of how they have done so, or have any funky array walk tips to do so?

Comment: Please go and learn about recursion.

Comment: @blockhead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23882

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution can be achieved with variable references (aka "pointers"), for more information see http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

```
<?php

$foo = array();
$foo['/'] = 'value';
$foo['/foo'] = 'value';
$foo['/foo/bar'] = 'value';
$foo['/test'] = 'value';
$foo['/test/tester'] = 'value';
$foo['/hello'] = 'value';
$foo['/hello/world'] = 'value';
$foo['/hello/world/blah'] = 'value';

function nest(&$foo)
{
    $new = array();
    foreach ($foo as $path => $value)
    {
        $pointer =& $new;
        $currentPath = '';
        if ($pathParts = explode('/', trim($path, '/'))) {
            while($nextKey = array_shift($pathParts)) {
                $currentPath .= '/' . $nextKey;
                if (!isset($pointer['children'][$currentPath])) {
                    $pointer['children'][$currentPath] = array();
                }
                $pointer =& $pointer['children'][$currentPath];
            }
        }
        $pointer['value'] = $value;
    }
    return $new ? array('/' => $new) : array();
}

print_r($foo);
print_r(nest($foo));

?>
```

Comment: Note that this example is called "iterative" because it does not use recursion. I'm not sure what a recursive version would look like but I invite @blockhead or someone else to try :-)