# PHP: Access nested object properties via dot notation

Tags: javascript, php, oop, coding-style, standards

What is a simple method to access nested properties of an object via a "dot notion" string?

For example:

```
#..........................Classes..........................

class Colour            |   class Eye       |   class Person
{                       |   {               |   {
    $hexValue = #36ff00 |       $colour;    |       $eyes;
}                       |   }               |   }

#..........................Example..........................

$john = new Person;

$eyes = [new Eye, new Eye];

$eyes[0]->color = new Colour;

$eyes[1]->color = new Colour;

$john->eyes = [new Eye, new Eye];

#..........................Question..........................

# How can we do something like this?

$eyeColour = Helper::dot($john, 'eyes[0].colour.hexValue');
```

Comment: Same direction: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38087608/3933332 just got asked 15 minutes ago. Also see the comments to get some ideas.

Comment: That is for array access, there are a plethora of examples and packages dealing with array dot access. Although none for objects / class instances.

Answer (score 7):

There is no *simple method* to do this. You'll have to parse the path string and then reach the desired value step by step.

Checkout the [Symfony PropertyAccess Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access/introduction.html). It can be used as a standalone library without the rest of the framework.

```
use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccess;

$accessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();

$eyeColour = $accessor->getValue($john, 'eyes[0].colour.hexValue');
```

Comment: Perfect, I have actually come across this library in the past. +1 for the use of library over an example.