# Get value from form multidimensional array named Element

Tags: php, forms, multidimensional-array

I have a form that builds a JSON string to be saved inside a database table
where the form elements names are array based to improve JSON creation.

The names are created dynamically like the following:

```
table[column][name][0]
table[column][name][1]
table[column][name][2]
table[column][name][3]
```

But I am actually running accross a situation.

I know that I can access this POST value as:

```
$_POST[table][column][name][0]
$_POST[table][column][name][1]
 //.. and so on
```

But the problem is that I receive the element name as a string

```
table][column][name][0]
```

How can I get

```
$_POST[table][column][name][0]
```

from

```
table[column][name][0]
```

Comment: You can trivially change the string you have to `table.column.name.0` and then the answers from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537148/string-with-array-structure-to-array/8537238#8537238) would work without modification. Not voting as duplicate yet, but do take a look.

Comment: @Jon Changing the element name is not allowed. It's legacy code that used to only create the JSON string, not update.

Comment: Changing the element name is not allowed but it's not that hard to call `preg_replace` after you have received it, right? Or perhaps to adapt the code from the linked answer to work with your particular format?

Comment: @Joh I may be missing something here but I don`t have (quoted) $_POST["table][column][name][0]"]. I have $_POST['table'] = array(
 'column' => array(
    'name' => array(
   0 => 'THE VALUE'
    )
    )
);

Comment: Please read carefully the question I linked to and its answers. They are about *setting* values, but getting them out is the same really.

Comment: @Jon I guess I got it right now. Considering the linked answer from hakre I just treated my string from a variable $key = str_replace("]", "", $elementName) and set $target = $_POST. The last resulting variable for $rv has now de value for $elementName to be matched on corresponding POST variable.