# Convert string to multdimensional array

Tags: php

I have the follow array of strings:

```
$arrayOfStrings = [
    0 => "item1",
    1 => "item2",
    2 => "item2.subitem1",
    3 => "item2.subitem2.a",
    4 => "item2.sutitem2.b"
]
```

And I need to convert this array of strings to multidimensional array, like this:

```
$multidimensionalArray = [
    0 => "item1",
    "item2" => [
        "subitem1",
        "subitem2" => [
            "a",
            "b"
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: What exactly is preventing you from accomplishing this? What attempt have you made? What was the result?

Comment: I just got it, thank's

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String with array structure to Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537148/string-with-array-structure-to-array)

Answer (score 0):

I just got it, as follows:

```
private function createArrayFromString($fields)
    {
        $arrayFields = [];
        foreach ($fields as $k => $field) {
            $field = explode('.', $field);
            $count = count($field);
            if ($count > 1) {
                $parent = $field[0];
                unset($field[0]);
                $nextFields[] = implode('.', $field);
                $arrayFields[$parent] = $this->createArrayFromString($nextFields);
            } else {
                $arrayFields[$k] = $field[0];
            }

        }
        return $arrayFields;
    }
```